# Problem with relative imports in project with lot of nested folders

Tags: python, import

Apologies in advance if my question seems basic. I'm relatively new to Python and I'm currently in the process of learning the language.
I want to use relative paths in my project to refer to files (e.g. config files, log files etc); browsing online i found that it is good practice to have a file in the root directory or in a first level directory that contains a sort of `ROOT_DIR` variable that you can import and use in the rest of the project. Given the following code structure, I'm having problems implementing this solution:

```
root_dir
├── config
│   ├── config.ini
│   ├── definitions.py
├── libs
│   ├── lib_1
│   │   ├── A.py
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── test_A.py
│   ├── lib_2
│   │   ├── B.py
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── test_B.py
├── main.py
```

The content of the `definitions.py` file is:

```
import os
ROOT_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

This works fine if I use `ROOT_DIR` from within the `main.py` that is one level above definitions.py but does not work if I use `ROOT_DIR` from, say, `A.py` or `B.py`, doing `from config.definitions import ROOT_DIR`.
I tried adding `__init__.py` files to every directory but nothing. PyCharm seems to be fine and recognizes the import but if I run `A.py` or `B.py` from the terminal either from the root folder or from `lib_1/lib_2`, ModuleNotFoundError is fired.

Can anyone explain to me how can I achieve this behaviour using relative imports from any subfolder of the project? What is the pythonic way to do so?
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing comes from how you're running your Python scripts. When you run a Python script directly, Python's module search path (`sys.path`) begins from the script's directory. As a result, if you're inside `lib_1` or `lib_2` and try to run `A.py` or `B.py` directly, Python won't be able to find the `config` module, as it's neither in the script's directory nor in the `PYTHONPATH`.

Here is the solution: instead of running `A.py` or `B.py` directly, you should execute them as modules using Python's `-m` flag, starting from the root directory of your project. Here's how you can do that:

1. Open your terminal and navigate to the root directory of your project (`root_dir`).
2. Run your Python modules with the following commands:

```bash
python -m libs.lib_1.A
python -m libs.lib_2.B
```

Here, the `-m` flag tells Python to run the module as a script, and Python will be able to correctly resolve the relative import `from config.definitions import ROOT_DIR`.

This is a Pythonic way of dealing with module organization and it makes your code more maintainable and portable without having to worry about manipulating `sys.path` or about operating system specific paths.

Also, remember to add an empty `__init__.py` file in each directory that you want Python to recognize as a package. This includes `root_dir/config`, `root_dir/libs`, `root_dir/libs/lib_1`, `root_dir/libs/lib_2`, and the `test` subdirectories. These files can be empty, but they need to be present.